# Continue[ ] command will not work within If statement

Tags: functions, conditional

I am currently using the Module command for dynamical programming.

Within the Module, I have an If statement

```
If[b[i] == 0, {imax = i, Break[]}, Continue[]];
Return[b[imax - 1]]
```

When I go to use the program, the returned values have $ sign followed by a number.

However, if I remove the square brackets after Continue then it is fine.

I don't understand why it is like this if somebody could explain that would be great

Comment: This question requires full code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen your full code but general answer is:

`Break` and `Continue` in Mathematica just like any other programming languages should be use in loops (with few exceptions in other languages)

Using these two commands without being in `For`, `While` or `Do` loops will raise `nofwd` Error which described in [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Break/nofwd.html) as:

> This message is generated when Break is evaluated and there is no enclosing loop from which to exit.

for example this code will print `i` to `i-5` number, with a loop that run only 5 times, it will check if number is not zero then it will print the number and decrease it by 1:

```
i = 8;
Do[If[i == 0, Break[], Print[i]; i = i - 1;], 5]
```

Output:

```
8
7
6
5
4
```

but if I use numbers lower than 5, it will print `i` to `0`, code will reach i==0 and executes `Break` and will exit `Do` loop:

```
i = 3;
Do[If[i == 0, Break[], Print[i]; i = i - 1;], 5]
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
```

but if I use `Break` without loop:

```
i = 0;
If[i == 0, Break[];]
```

I will get an error, because there is no loop to break or continue.

```
Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[].
```

In your code there is no need for `Continue` or `Break` because Mathematica will reach the end of your condition commands (true or false) and will execute the next line

you code should be like this:

```
If[b[i] == 0, imax = i;];
(*or*)
If[b[i] == 0, imax = i;,Null];
```

Also if you want to create a recursive function, you should play with `Return` and `If` not `break` and `continue`.

Keep in mind that if you provide more code, we could better explain your problem.
All the code tested on Mathematica 12.2.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to answer your question with the available information but here is what I think you are trying to accomplish.

```
Module[{},
 data = {14, 6, 0, 2, 13, 5, 8, 0, 9, 19, 0, 9, 1, 16, 13, 16, 16, 0, 
   9, 16};
 Do[If[data[[i]] == 0, imax = i; Break[], Continue[]], {i, 20}];
 data[[imax - 1]]
 ]
```